# Placeholder for dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to know how can I have a place holder inside the drop-down menu, something like "select a city". how can I do this?

```
function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr)
{
    $(selobj).empty();
    $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i,obj)
        {
            $(selobj).append(
                 $('<option></option>')
                        .val(obj[nameattr])
                        .html(obj[nameattr]));
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to have the first `option` be "Select a city" and give it a null value. You'll want to do some validation later to make sure this was selected before submitting, too.

```
function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr)
{
  // save the jQuery obj in a var for efficiency.
  $selobj = $(selobj);
  $selobj.empty();
  $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
  {
    $selobj.append(
        $('<option>Select a City</option>')
                    .val('null')
    );

    $.each(data, function(i,obj)
    {
        $selobj.append(
             $('<option></option>')
                    .val(obj[nameattr])
                    .html(obj[nameattr]));
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the option before the loop:

```
....
 $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
{
    $(selobj).append('<option>Select City</option>') //here
    $.each(data, function(i,obj)
    {
        $(selobj).append(
             $('<option></option>')
                                .....
```